# AttributeError: module 'rasa.nlu.utils' has no attribute 'pycloud_pickle'

Tags: python, rasa-nlu

I am trying to implement Sentiment_Analyzer in rasa based on the instructions given in the rasa official site. But it seems to be for the older version. Anyway the only change that doesn't work now is persisting the learnt model. The previous versions had the method 
`utils.pycloud_pickle(classifier_file, self)`
to do this. Is there any replacement for this in the newer version of rasa (1.0.1), or has it been completely removed?

```
def persist(self, file_name: Text, model_dir: Text) -> Optional[Dict[Text, Any]]:
    classifier_file = os.path.join(model_dir, SENTIMENT_MODEL_FILE_NAME)
    utils.pycloud_pickle(classifier_file, self)
    return {"classifier_file": SENTIMENT_MODEL_FILE_NAME}
```

I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'rasa.nlu.utils' has no attribute 'pycloud_pickle'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pickle module from python, e.g.

```py
import pickle

with open(classifier_file) as f:
   pickle.dump(self, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

install rasa==1.5.0.
Downgrading existing rasa resolved for me.